# Change Calculator Using Java

Tags: java, calculator, calc

I need to create a program that can calculate change in the most efficient way possible. Ex. 3 Quarters instead of 75 pennies. It is only single dollar bills, quarters, dimes, etc. However, there are a few rules i need to follow.

1) Isolate both the dollars and cents components of the original input string into separate sub strings.

2) Use the Integer utility class to parse these two sub strings into primitive integer values.

3) You may not use any typecasting in your work.

4) Test thoroughly to ensure that no rounding errors remain.

The code is what I did initially, but i am always a penny off for some values

```
public class ChangeCalculator
{
public static void Main (String args[]){
    double NumberOfMoney = Double.parseDouble(args [0]);
    int NumberOfCoins = (int)(NumberOfMoney * 100);

    System.out.println("Amount of Money: " + NumberOfMoney + "\n");

    int NumberOfDollars = (int)(NumberOfCoins/100);
    NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins - 100 * NumberOfDollars;
    System.out.println("Dollars: " + NumberOfDollars);

    int NumberOfQuarters = (int)(NumberOfCoins/25);
    NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins - 25 * NumberOfQuarters;
    System.out.println("Quarters: " + NumberOfQuarters);

    int NumberOfDimes = (int)(NumberOfCoins/10);
    NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins - 10 * NumberOfDimes;
    System.out.println("Dimes: " + NumberOfDimes);

    int NumberOfNickels = (int)(NumberOfCoins/5);
    NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins - 5 * NumberOfNickels;
    System.out.println("Nickels: " + NumberOfNickels);

    int NumberOfPennies = (int)(NumberOfCoins/1);
    NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins - 1 * NumberOfPennies;
    System.out.println("Pennies: " + NumberOfPennies);
}
}
```

the input $1.15 should output 
Dollars: 1
Quarters: 0
Dimes: 1
Nickels: 1
Pennies: 0
BUT it outputs
Dollars: 1
Quarters: 0
Dimes: 1
Nickels: 0
Pennies: 4

Comment: "$1.15 should output Dollars: 1 Quarters: 0 Dimes: 1 Nickels: 5 Pennies: 0"
Should it not be: 
"Dollars: 1 Quarters: 0 Dimes: 1 Nickels: 1 Pennies: 0?"

Comment: For your Input, please try printing NumberOfCoins variable first and debug.  The initial value of NumberOfCoins is not calculated correctly.

Comment: @AleksW thanks I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Try this as your second line in `Main`:

```
int NumberOfCoins = (int)Math.round(NumberOfMoney * 100);
```

The reason this is that `NumberOfMoney * 100` is `114.999999999`, and so `(int)(NumberOfMoney * 100)` is `114`. In general, you should be careful not to trust the value of `double` and `float` variables to be exact.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that double is not as precise as some people may have lead you to believe. In your code, the problem relies on

`int NumberOfCoins = (int)NumberOfMoney * 100;`

as the output of this operation is 114.999999999... 
There are 2 options here, you can either round the operation using `Math.round`or use another type that is more precise but slower like `BigDecimal`.

You can use BigDecimal if you want that precision but the basic operators like `+,-,/*` doesnt exist on BigDecimal but you can use their methods `add, multiply, substract`, etc.

**Update 1:**
Code review
Ideally the naming of you variables should start with lowercase and then all the following words, capital letter for the beginning.
eg.

`NumberOfMoney` should be `numberOfMoney`
`NumberOfCoins` should be `numberOfCoins`
The names can be improved but that is ok for the moment.

If you divide a `int` by another `int` the final value will be always an `int` there is no need to cast it.
eg

```java
//The following statements are equal
int NumberOfDollars = (int)(NumberOfCoins/100);
int NumberOfDollars = NumberOfCoins / 100;
```

This operation is overly complicated and you can simplyfy it more

```java
//from
int NumberOfDollars = NumberOfCoins / 100;
NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins - 100 * NumberOfDollars;

//to
int NumberOfDollars = NumberOfCoins / 100;
NumberOfCoins = NumberOfCoins % 100;
```

**Update 2:**
From the rules that you posted, you are not following rule 1,2 and 3.
For rule 1, it is asking you to isolate the 2 components of the String. The first componen is the dollars values and the second one is the cents values.

```
String amountValue = "1.15";
String dollaralue = "1" // you need to figure out how to do this.
String centValue = "15" // same
```

For rule 2, check the documentation for [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and specificly to parseInt.

For rule 3, this is typecasting `int NumberOfCoins = (int)(NumberOfMoney * 100);`.

Answer (score 1):

change your `int NumberOfCoins = (int)(NumberOfMoney * 100);`
 to `int NumberOfCoins = (int)(Math.round(NumberOfMoney * 100));`

As other peers have mentioned double and float can't be really trusted while dealing with currencies, worth reading [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are seeing are related to the fact that you aren't following instruction 3, to avoid type casting.

In several places you do something like:

```
int NumberOfCoins = (int)(NumberOfMoney * 100);
```

That's casting, and casting between `int` and `double` can cause the rounding errors you are seeing. You can work around this by rounding in particular ways.

However, I think you'd do well to follow the first instruction you have:

```
1) Isolate both the dollars and cents components of the original input string into separate sub strings.
```

Then you'll be dealing with integers and can do your calculations more cleanly.